# Distribution of an autoregressive process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, time-series, z-transform

Say that we are given a AR process. Also, lets assume that the residuals of the process come form a distribution $P_R$ which, while known to us, is not necessarily normal.

Can I derive the distribution of the process?